# Am getting error " Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchAll('UPDATE nmcatalo...') "when am executing UPDATE Query?

Tags: upgrade, magento-1, table

[image]

```
public function listAction()
{  
    $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
    $readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');       
    $qur = 'SELECT * FROM nmcatalog_category_product where category_id = 3 AND product_id = 1';
    $results1 = $readConnection->fetchAll($qur);
    if(!empty($results1)){
      $writeConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');
      $updatequry = 'UPDATE nmcatalog_category_product SET position = 6 where category_id = 3 AND product_id = 1';
      $updateresult = $writeConnection->fetchAll($updatequry);
    }else{
      echo "Array Empty";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:

change fetchAll with query

```
public function listAction()
{  
    $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
    $readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');       
    $qur = 'SELECT * FROM nmcatalog_category_product where category_id = 3 AND product_id = 1';
    $results1 = $readConnection->fetchAll($qur);
    if(!empty($results1)){
      $writeConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');
      $updatequry = 'UPDATE nmcatalog_category_product SET position = 6 where category_id = 3 AND product_id = 1';
      $updateresult = $writeConnection->query($updatequry);
    }else{
      echo "Array Empty";
    }

}
```